# ¿Cómo pasar una variable de un archivo a otro?

Tags: javascript, variables

¿Cómo puedo pasar la varibale `p` a `test.js`?

```
----main.js----
 var p="hola";


----test.js---
alert(-la variable p aqui-);
```

¿De qué forma se puede hacer?

Comment: Eso depende, ¿son estos módulos?

Answer (score 0):

debes añadir el archivo main.js antes que test.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

De esta manera tienes acceso a todas las variables y funciones de main.js en test.js